# Show div on click and scroll to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function to show/hide a div on click and I would like the page to scroll down to that div on show function. I have included the ScrollTop function but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my code:

```
$('#output').hide();

$('#readMore').click(function(){
    $('#output').show(150);
    $('#readMore').hide(150);
      return false;
    $('html, body').scrollTop($('#output').offset().top);
});

$('#readLess').click(function(){
    $('#output').hide(150);
    $('#readMore').show(150);
});
```

Comment: Where you include the `return` statement, the function exits and all following code is omitted.

Comment: Thanks, I now realise why it wasn't scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Please put the `return false;` at the end.

```
$('#readMore').click(function(){
    $('#output').show(150);
    $('#readMore').hide(150);
    $('html, body').scrollTop($('#output').offset().top);
    return false; // Please put the return false; at the end.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#output').hide();

$('#readMore').click(function(){
$('#output').show(150);
$('#readMore').hide(150);
$('html, body').scrollTop($('#output').offset().top);
 return false;//return  need to be placed here
});

$('#readLess').click(function(){
$('#output').hide(150);
$('#readMore').show(150);
});
```